# select box displaced in Firefox after transform:scale()

Tags: javascript, html, css

A scaled DIV is containing two select boxes.
Due to scaling the select boxes are changing position.
But after opening the select box the options are display at the position it would be without scaling the parent div

please check Fiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/wJ4H9/

Fail in FF 28

works well in Chrome and Opera

code:

```
<div style="transform: scale(0.8);transform-origin: center center 0px; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0;">
    <select style="position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%"> 
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>

    <select style="position:absolute; top:60%; left:30%"> 
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a bug in Firefox. You should file a bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).

In Chrome, once you add `-webkit-transform:scale(0.8)`, the dropdown menu is correctly positioned. (See http://jsfiddle.net/wJ4H9/2/) However, note that the options are not scaled down.

Comment: I think you are right - I'll try a workaround for my Probem and post this to bugzilla

Comment: Very old question, but may one scale also the options?