# Scaling issue in combobox options (mozilla firefox )

Tags: css, scale, mozilla

i am adjusting a parent div to fit clients browser area.

-> in chrome i have used the zoom property which correctly scales all elements inside including combobox

-> And in mozilla, it doesn't scale the 'options of the combobox', it actually lies away.

```
<div style="transform: scale(0.8);">
<select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
</select>
```

[image: Issue image. Combobox and the options]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/19mkxd8g/)

i found the same issue question here : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22713858/select-box-displaced-in-firefox-after-transformscale) but this only talks about listing issues.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely looks like a bug in firefox. I too was facing similar problem. As a temporary hack I replaced my select boxes with a light weight jQuery plugin called selectric. See - http://jsfiddle.net/19mkxd8g/5/

```
        $(function(){
            $('select').selectric();
        });
```