# Scale on an input inside a div with Firefox doesnt work?

Tags: css, firefox, scaletransform

Any idea how to solve this `Firefox` dysfunction : incorrect positioning of `combo-box` options (`html select`) with a `css scale` transformation applied.

My version of Firefox is `49.0b1`.

When I remove or replace the scale (by another) transformation 1.5 in `css` it places correctly.

```css
    body {
      transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
      transform: scale(1.5); //That does not work correctly
      border: solid red 1px;
    }

    #container {
      width: 1150px;
      height: 700px;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: block;
      left: 50px;
      top: 200px;
      border: solid dodgerblue 1px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <select name="select">
      <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
      <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

[Here a fiddle exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/pL8vkyfw/)

**I already know** this is a `Firefox` bug, but is there an alternative without replacing the standard `select` by anonther external library ?

Comment: The fiddle does not seem to exist. Also please always provide the code in the question directly as well.

Comment: I've corrected de link thx

Comment: Please add the code to your question as well (not just a link to the fiddle).

Comment: @Sunitrams' no, there is no alternative but substitute the select with something else :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug with Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455164

The only workaround at the moment seems to be using an alternative such as [Select2](https://select2.github.io/). Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27134660

Comment: a 8 years old bug, using a tierce librairy seems too heavy, any other css or js alternative ?

Comment: There are simpler, lighter libraries than Select2, I put it there just as an example. It depends on your specific needs in the end, maybe even a simple JS dropdown could do, but we don't know your code architecture.